# Xpath has an invalid token

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I Want to get all links in a html page with "ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24" class name with xpath.

i write thic code :

```
string links = node.SelectSingleNode(".//a[(@class,'ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24')]").GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```

but i get this error:

```
'.//a[(@class,'ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24')]' has an invalid token.
```

Comment: Can you show the snippet of html containing that `class` attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace comma with equal sign and remove parenthesis as below to match element by exact class name:

```
string links = node.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@class='ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24']").GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```

Or you can use `contains()` to match element by partial class name:

```
string links = node.SelectSingleNode(".//a[contains(@class,'ac-algo fz-l ac-21th lh-24')]").GetAttributeValue("href", null);
```